# Undefined reference on shared library JNI

Tags: java, compiler-construction, linker, java-native-interface

Okay, so I'm developing something With JNI + C, and the java code calls a method on a .c that uses another compiled C code, so Java -> C -> C.

but when running,  if I don use the second C code, things work fine, but when I use it:

```
java: symbol lookup error: /home/adriano/Área de Trabalho/229/DFT/libDFT.so: undefined symbol: newComplex
```

while newComplex is in complex.h

This is how Iḿ compiling the shared lib:

```
libDFT.so : DFT.o complex.o
gcc -shared -ansi -pedantic -Wall -O0 -g -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -fPIC -I${JNI_INCLUDE} -I${JNI_INCLUDE}/linux/ -o $@ $<
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What means "Java -> C -> C" ? The C library is calling another C library? Which one of them is "libDFT.so" and which one is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
libDFT.so : DFT.o complex.o
        gcc -shared ... -o $@ $<
```

From [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables):

> $< 
>   The name of the **first** prerequisite.

You want:

```
libDFT.so : DFT.o complex.o
        gcc -shared ... -o $@ $^
```

(The names of **all** the prerequisites.)